# Is there any way to go to all links in page in watin i have used the following code but no use

Tags: c#, testing, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, watin

couple of days back i have used the same code to go to each and every page, today it doesn't work. Does anyone know an other approach than this:

```
 var browser = new IE("http//www.xyz.com");


            foreach (Link l in browser.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(l.Url);
                if (l.Url.IndexOf("javascript") == -1)
                {
                    browser.GoTo(l.Url);
                    browser.WaitForComplete();
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    browser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(browser.Url));

                    browser.Back();



                }

            }


error Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `NullReferenceException` means that you are trying to call a method or access a field/property of a null object. You need to step through this code and figure out what is null when it shouldn't be using the debugger.

Comment: debuggin in visual stuido while using watin make life miserable,

Comment: I see. Sorry, I'm not familiar with WatiN. You may have to debug it the old-fashioned way then: by adding some sort of print statement, if that's possible. You just have to find the null somehow.